# Child views are pushed inside the parent ExpandableListView component

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have been developing multi-level ExpandableListView components for a client requirement. So i have 4 levels right now and when i click on the last item that is the 4th level, the parent items are pushed inside the ExpandableListView which is not what i want and the correct way of doing it. Please help me as to how i can avoid this when child views are clicked the parent views are expanded and scrolled accordingly so that parent items will not go missing inside the other views. Below is a screenshot of what i have right now and the layout files for these are given below.

[image]

client_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableList2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:indicatorLeft="250dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

property_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPropertyHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/propertyList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />

</LinearLayout>
```

unit_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblPropertyHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/propertyList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ticket_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="33dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="17dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you use four expandable listviews or three? Why are you not explaining how this all should work?

Comment: I'm using 3 expandable views actually and the last child view of the exapandableview is a textview. In this scenario that is "Property1". After clicking the 1, 2 and 3 rd level do you see that parent items are being pushed inside?

Comment: "Property1" can never be a last child as it is on the parent level of "Unit". So i dont understand what you are telling. The last visible "Property1" is partly covered by the following parent. Is this what you mean? Are no more "Property1" items -completely- covered?

Comment: Is the last visible Property1 collapsed/expanded? Does it have children. What i miss in your description is if all works as expected but that something a last item is partly covered. Is that the only problem? You are talking about expanding on the 4th level. But Property1 is on the 2nd. So again i do not understand.

Comment: A expanded property can be seen just above what i have highlighted where "Unit" is the child. So when i click on "Property1" it shows 2x"Unit" items which is correct. but if you can see what ive highlited the balance set of property1 items goes inside that expandable view. I want to stop that

Comment: You did not react to the point and not complete on my remarks. Why not?

Comment: Well last Property1 is collapsed and it does have children that is two of "Unit"s. The problem is when i click Property1 (As i have highlited in the image), the property1 group expands and because of the automatic scroller, some of the property1 items are inside the property expandablelistview. So that becomes two scrollers. How do i get this working?

Comment: You did not answer all. Scrollers? Where is the second one?

Comment: In ExpandableListViews there are automatic scrollers. So like i said before there are 3 expandable components in my project.

Comment: No you said `So that becomes two scrollers.`. And i asked why you said that. What does it have to do with the problem? Elaborate.

Comment: Maybe not. since you understand the problem why dont you tell me the answer?